# Pegar registros que estão há 3 dias para vencer

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamado `cotas` que tem uma coluna `ultimo_recebimento`, nessa coluna está a data na forma de `time` do dia que será a última recebimento do usuário. Preciso pegar todos os registros que estão a 3 dias de vencer. Por exemplo, se tenho um registro que o último recebimento é dia 30/12/2015 então se hoje for dia 27/12/2015 ele lista. Preciso fazer isso no PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvido**

Utilizei o seguinte comando MySQL:

```
$hoje_tres = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2015-12-28')+(60*60*24*3));

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cotas WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(ultimo_recebimento, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$hoje_tres'");
```

Answer (score 0):

No Mysql a query a ser utilizada é

```
$sql = "select * from cotas where datediff(ultimo_recebimento,now()) <= 3";
```

A Função **now()** do MySql retorno a hora que a query foi executada.

***Utilize mais o banco de dados, operações como está são facilmente executadas pelo banco de dados e é mais rápido.